# How to include all views from another app in home page? django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I recently started creating a webpage with django.

I want to integrate a newsletter System into my page. Since I do not want to write it entirely on my own I have used this one: [Django-Newsletter](https://github.com/dokterbob/django-newsletter)

How do I include one template or in the best case all templates from the newsletter app into a block of my home.html template with all the dynamic content?

With an include statement, the dynamic content like the following is not rendered.

```
{% for form in formset.forms %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ form.id }}{{ form.newsletter }}
<a href="{% url "newsletter_detail" form.instance.newsletter.slug %}">    {{ form.instance.newsletter.title }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ form.subscribed }}</td>
      </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I have thought about using "render_to_response" or a "inclusion tag", but I am not sure of any of the both sulution is the right way to do it, nor how to do it.

**Folder structure:**

```
application/
    myapp/
        templates/
            home.html
            ...
    newsletter/
        templates/
            newsletter-list.html
            ...
```

Probably the solution to my problem will seem ridiculously simple to more experienced developers, but I ask you to answer as extensive as possible.

Comment: I don't see why you need to include _all_ templates into one template. We can probably be of more help if you can explain the actual need.

Comment: Probably I have not expressed myself clear enough. In the first place I want to include a simple form where you can insert your email, to subscribe to a newsletter. But It would be even better, if all controls, that the app offers, like having different forms for guests and users and controls if you are already subscribed, could be integrated in a block on the main page.

Comment: It uses so called [_stub_-templates](http://django-newsletter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html) for embedding into your own project. You can directly modify those placeholder templates to fit into your site's look and feel.

Comment: Sure, I could do that, but that would mean, that those templates would stand on their own, wouldn't it? I do not wand a page just to apply for the newsletter, but I want to embed the form on my home page.